# How to use SAS url at directory level in ADLS Gen2 to get contents of folder using python

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have sas url at directory level and want to use to read contents of directory instead of using connection string

Answer (score 0):

**Follow below Syntax:**

## Create mount

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
        source = "wasbs://<container_name>@<storage_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net/",
        mount_point = "/mnt/t123",
        extra_configs = {"fs.azure.sas.<container_name>.<storage_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net":"Your_SAS_token"})
```

## Read csv file

```
file_location ="wasbs://<container_name>@<storage_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net/filename.csv"
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("inferSchema", "true").option("header", "true").option("delimiter",",").load(file_location)
 
display(df)
```

[image: Ref1]
[image: Ref2]

**Reference:**

[Reading and Writing data in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen 2 with Azure Databricks by Ryan Kennedy](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6499/reading-and-writing-data-in-azure-data-lake-storage-gen-2-with-azure-databricks/)

[Mount ADLS Gen2 storage account provided by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/adls-gen2/azure-datalake-gen2-sp-access#---mount-adls-gen2-storage)